# NullInjectorError: No provider for _CoalescedStyleScheduler

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination

I am trying to follow the [following tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_material7/angular_material7_paginator.htm), but I keep the getting the error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatTable -> _CoalescedStyleScheduler]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatTable -> _CoalescedStyleScheduler]: 
 NullInjectorError: No provider for _CoalescedStyleScheduler!
```

thrown out and the page does not render fully. My source code is the following:

```
<mat-paginator [length] = "100" [pageSize] = "10" [pageSizeOptions] = "[5, 10, 25, 100]" (page) = "pageEvent = $event"></mat-paginator>
```

Yes, I did import all the required modules as stated in the tutorial.

**UPDATE**
Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.2",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^9.3.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.11.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "^8.5.6",
    "any-observable": "^0.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "json-server": "^0.16.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.15",
    "ng-mat-search-bar": "^9.0.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "subscribable": "^0.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
```

**UPDATE 2**
After importing the _CoalescedStyleScheduler I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/table/coalesced-style-scheduler' in 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Project1\frontend\src\app'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
```

**UPDATE 3**
My app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
import { NgMatSearchBarModule } from 'ng-mat-search-bar';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { WavesModule, InputsModule, ButtonsModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { WorkDocumentComponent } from './work-document/work-document.component';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import { TabArchiveMailOrderComponent } from './tab-archive-mail-order/tab-archive-mail-order.component';
import { TabDataContextComponent } from './tab-data-context/tab-data-context.component';
import { TabReceiverComponent } from './tab-receiver/tab-receiver.component';
import { TabSenderComponent } from './tab-sender/tab-sender.component';
import { TabTemplatesComponent } from './tab-templates/tab-templates.component';
import { DialogCancelComponent } from './dialog-cancel/dialog-cancel.component';
import { DialogLoadingComponent } from './dialog-loading/dialog-loading.component';
import { TabMainComponent } from './tab-main/tab-main.component';
import { DialogTemplateCancelComponent } from './dialog-template-cancel/dialog-template-cancel.component';

import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatDividerModule, MatDivider} from '@angular/material/divider';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { NotFoundPageComponent } from './not-found-page/not-found-page.component';
import { GlobalDataService } from './services/global-data.service';
import { TonicViewerComponent } from './tonic-viewer/tonic-viewer.component';
import { ModalModule } from './_modal';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { _CoalescedStyleScheduler } from '../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/table/coalesced-style-scheduler';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WorkDocumentComponent,
    TabArchiveMailOrderComponent,
    TabDataContextComponent,
    TabReceiverComponent,
    TabSenderComponent,
    TabTemplatesComponent,
    DialogCancelComponent,
    DialogLoadingComponent,
    TabMainComponent,
    DialogTemplateCancelComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NotFoundPageComponent,
    TonicViewerComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    Ng2SearchPipeModule,
    NgMatSearchBarModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    WavesModule,
    InputsModule,
    ButtonsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    ModalModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DialogCancelComponent,
    DialogTemplateCancelComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-US'},
    GlobalDataService,
    _CoalescedStyleScheduler
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  title = 'App';

 }
```

Comment: _CoalescedStyleScheduler is this the custom service you have?

Comment: @JoharZaman No, it's definetely not a custom service

Comment: The service is defined in angular material. @Munchkin what version of angular are you running?

Comment: Can you add the full error please?

Comment: try adding `_CoalescedStyleScheduler` in providers.

Comment: like this: `providers: [_CoalescedStyleScheduler]`

Comment: @RazRonen just did, sorry for not adding it earlier

Comment: @JoharZaman my IDE is complaining that it cannot find the name

Comment: try `import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';` and not `import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material';` maybe..

Comment: you can `import { _CoalescedStyleScheduler} from cdk/table/coalesced-style-scheduler'` and then `providers: [_CoalescedStyleScheduler]` like Munchkin mentioned

Comment: it also complains about the (page) part... the error is ` Property 'pageEvent' does not exist on type 'WorkDocumentComponent'.`

Comment: I removed it and new errors appear, please see updated question (UPDATE 2)

Comment: You are giving it absolute path right?
Try giving it relative path to node_modules location just to see if this will fix the issue.

Comment: @RazRonen Setting it to `import { _CoalescedStyleScheduler } from '../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/table/coalesced-style-scheduler';` throws the same error

Comment: can you post your module please? the one that imports MatPaginatorModule?

Comment: And the component with the template containing `mat-paginator` is declared in this module right?

Comment: @RazRonen I didn't get your question, but I think the answer is yes

Comment: got this after updating angular from angular 10.0.0 to 10.0.8. Looks like libs incompatibility probalem

Comment: Could be cdk": "^10.1.2", issue, I've downgraded it to 10.0.2 and the error has gone

Comment: @user656449 you're a genius, npm install @angular/cdk@10.0.2 solved the issue! You can answer and I will accept it as a correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: There is apparently a second reason why you might get this (I just saw it on a fork of an app I am working on).

I've now seen two ways to produce this:

## Problem 1: version differences between material and cdk

In **package.json** `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/material` have sufficiently different version requirements that cause cdk to be >10.0.2 and material to be <=10.0.2.

To fix: make sure you are using the same version for cdk and material. These packages only seem to be tested in lock step with each other.

## Problem 2: something inherits from CdkTable (original answer)

I'm assuming you override a CdkTable or MatTable somewhere or use a library that does so.

You have to provide a _CoalescedStyleScheduler in the providers for that override just like as is done in MatTable itself:

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/1b1c31e91e029418f0f2477242149b10c5cc7832/src/material/table/table.ts#L35

You have to do this or upgrade your library that has a CdkTable implementation to a version that does...

Comment: Adding providers did not work.. Seems that user656449's solution is the correct one..

Comment: Ok, I have to be honest, I did not try that specific linked syntax though..

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! A note though, Intellij is complaining that @angular/cdk/table does not export anything named _CoalescedStyleScheduler, but the compiler is happy and the error is no more.

Answer (score 3):

got this after updating angular from 10.0.0 to 10.0.8. Looks like it's libs compatibility problem – after downgrading cdk from "^10.1.2 to 10.0.2 the error has gone

Answer (score 2):

@angular/cdk introduced _CoalescedStyleScheduler into CdkTable which MatTable implements somewhere between 10.0.2 and later.

In order to use MatTable with the new version you have to update your @angular/material to version released 27.7.2020 or later.

Generally keep your @angular/material the same version as @angular/cdk for compatibility.

See relevant commit in mat-table.ts at https://github.com/angular/components/commit/ef8fc4f98c984825401cb10456782a66c663e4ef#diff-0fa17bba051db8d8fefff13603d28575